# How to calculate previous 'n' months from an input parameter in Solaris?

Tags: perl, unix, datetime, solaris

I am writing a script on a Solaris system, and I need to get the *n*th previous month from an input parameter (e.g. I need the value of the 13th month previous to 201308 - so my output needs to be `201207`, with `201308` coming as an input parameter to my shell script).

Most examples I found is using GNU but since my machine is a server and I don't have admin privileges, I am not able to install GNU there.

I have perl installed but I can't seem to bring out the exact code for this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given there is the `DateTime` module installed or you can install modules from CPAN (at least into your home directory):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use DateTime;

my $in = $ARGV[0] or die "No input";
my ( $year, $month ) = ( $in =~ m/^(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)$/ ) or die "Wrong format";
my $dt = DateTime->new( year => $year, month => $month );
$dt->subtract( months => 13 );
print $dt->strftime("%Y%m\n");
```

As requested a version without using the `DateTime` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $in = $ARGV[0] or die "No input";
my ( $year, $month ) = ( $in =~ m/^(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)$/ ) or die "Wrong format";
$month -= 13;
while ( $month < 1 ) {
    $year  -= 1;
    $month += 12;
}
printf "%04i%02i\n", $year, $month;
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I saved your code in a file named as datecalc and executed with the input parameter 201308. I am getting the following error message: Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8/aix-thread-multi /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8 /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.8.8/aix-thread-multi /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/opt/perl5/lib/site_perl .) at ./datecalc line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./datecalc line 3.

Comment: That means that the `DateTime` module is not installed. I'll post an update doing date math without DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with basic shell scripting using Solaris 10 ksh:

```
previousNMonth()
{
  y=$(echo $1|sed 's/..$//')
  m=$(echo $1|sed 's/^....//')
  m=$((m-$2))
  while [ $m -lt 1 ]; do m=$((m+12)); y=$((y-1)); done
  printf "%04d%02d\n" $y $m
} 

$ previousNMonth 201308 13
201207
```

If you are using Solaris 11, here is a ksh93 version which is pure shell, i.e. doesn't rely on external commands:

```
previousNMonth()
{
  y=${1:0:4}
  m=$((${1:4:2}-$2))
  while (( m < 1)); do m=$((m+12)); y=$((y-1)); done
  printf "%04d%02d\n" $y $m
}
```